# Scala: Cannot prove that Node <:< IdHolder[Int]

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion

I'm working on a project with both `java` and `scala` modules. I have a generic method that causes the error `Cannot prove that Node <:< IdHolder[Int]`:

```scala
def fetchElement[T](url: String)(implicit ev: T <:< IdHolder[Int]): util.TreeMap[Int, T] = {
   // some stuff
}
```

I have also this trait:

```scala
trait IdHolder[I] {
  val id: I
}
```

and a java class:

```java
public class Node implements Serializable, IdHolder<Integer>, Comparable<Node> {
    @Override
    public Integer id() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and I am using this method in my scala code:

```scala
val categories : util.TreeMap[Int, Node] = fetchElement(url)
```

I think I am telling scala that the generic parameter `T` is `Node` by specifying `categories`'s type as `util.TreeMap[Int, Node]`, but it does not detect the implicit conversion! Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Well, `summon[List[Integer] <:< List[Int]]` doesn't work either. I don't know what you're attempting there, but mixing implicits, inheritance, generics, primitive autoboxing, all in context of scala-java-interop looks like a rather questionable endeavor.

Comment: Where is your implicit definition , that will be implicitly added to `fetchElement` when you call it  ?

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip There is none. Here, the compiler is supposed to be generating evidence instances for `<:<` out of thin air, except that it cannot, because `IdHolder[Integer]` is unrelated to `IdHolder[Int]`.

Comment: Does it work if you make `Node` a Scala class? It if does, it does seem to be an interoperability issue.  One could open a bug about this: https://github.com/scala/bug, if it's on Scala 2.

Comment: Oh, I see what Andrey is talking about now.  Would switching fetchElement to receive an IdHolder[Integer]  work ? That could be a quick fix if it does.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Actually, I have abstracted away some details: the `Node` class is an entity for my persistent layer which is backed by Spring Data JPA and it needs to be a Java class. And my parallel logic side is written in Scala. That's why I implemented my classes this way.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip As @AndreyTyukin mentioned I supposed that the compiler himself can detect the __implicit__ conversion, but when I saw that it failed, I tried to pass the implicit definition as an argument declared as `val ev: Node <:< IdHolder[Int] = null` to fool compiler: `val categories : util.TreeMap[Int, Node] = fetchElement(url)(ev)`. It clears the compile error but in runtime, this `null` argument causes the `NullPointerException`. Do you have any better ideas for declaring implicit definition as an argument?

Comment: `A <:< B` means "A is supertype (or equal) to B". It doesn't consider implicit conversion in the equation. There used to be a separate generalized constraint `A <%< B` which meant "A is obtainable from B" (either by upcasting or conversion) but it was removed. If you want to use an implicit evidence which might convert the data (and you would because `scala.Int` is NOT `java.lang.Interger`), I suggest writing your own type class for that.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Ok. You are right. I was thinking that it still means "A is obtainable from B" and I was expecting that it can be done automatically. According to what @AlinGabrielArhip said, I prefer to use `Int` Autoboxing to `Integer` as a quick fix. Thank you, everyone!